# Run method after Keycloak Server startup

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am creating a custom SPI for Keycloak. How to execute the method after the Keycloak server startup?

Comment: What do you mean by "the method"? Please give more details on your SPI and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @sventorben I want to start a scheduled task and make an API request each hour. There is a really good method `timerProviderObject.scheduleTask(...)` in Keycloak. I want to call this method at Keycloak Server startup. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement an [Event Listener](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/15.0/server_development/#_events) and listen to the [`PostMigrationEvent`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/utils/PostMigrationEvent.html)
Your [`EventListenerProviderFactory`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/events/EventListenerProviderFactory.html) implementation has access to the [`KeycloakSession`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/provider/ProviderFactory.html#create-org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession-) which can be used to lookup the `TimerProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of sventorben won't work since the `EventListenerProvider` consumes events of type `org.keycloak.events.Event` or `org.keycloak.events.AdminEvent` whereas the `PostMigrationEvent` implements an `org.keycloak.provider.ProviderEvent`.

But the basic idea of consuming the `PostMigrationEvent` works when you do the following in the `postInit` of a Provider factory:

```java
import org.keycloak.events.EventListenerProviderFactory;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSessionFactory;
import org.keycloak.models.utils.PostMigrationEvent;

public class MyEventListenerProviderFactory
    implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

    ...

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
        factory.register(event -> {
            if (event instanceof PostMigrationEvent) {
                // execute your logic
            }
        });
    }

    ...
}
```